# Using Motion to Post pictures captured to API - rpi4

Tags: python, api, post, raspberry-pi, motion-detection

I am attempting to build a program that will automatically post the photos taken by motion from my usb webcam to a rest API, and have ran into some problems. My livestream works correctly, and it takes photos at the desired time.
I have my script to post the photo here:

```
on_picture_save home/pi/Documents/on_picture_save.py
```

(yes the semicolon is deleted)

How can I make the script use the file that has just been saved, or do it do it automatically so I would just have to do something like this?:

```
import requests

url = "https://api.emotuit.com/upload"

r = requests.post(url)

print(r.text)
```

The target directory all motion is saved in is home/pi/Monitor, and the photos are saved in their own directory based on the time of event like this:

```
picture_filename %v_%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M/%q
```

Any ideas would be appreciated, thanks!

Update: I have found how the code works in the command line, and changed it to that to make things easier:

```
on_picture_save curl -X POST api.link.com/here -F 'files=@/path/to/file/here.jpg;type=image.jpg'
```

I still will have issues printing the result though, so if there is any suggestions on how I would be able to do that though an additional .py file that'd be great.

Comment: maybe it can run with argument `on_picture_save.py filename` and later ypu can get it in\ code as `sys.argv[1]`

Comment: I'm not sure but `motion` may have option to create alias `latest.jpg` for last created picture and then you don't have to know its name. Eventually you can get all filenames `os.listdir()` and `sort()` them - and then last file on list should be the newest one.

Comment: [motion doc](https://motion-project.github.io/motion_config.html): _"A symbolic link called lastsnap.jpg is created in the target_dir and will always point to the latest snapshot"_

Comment: [motion doc - on_picture_save](https://motion-project.github.io/motion_config.html#on_picture_save): _Use %f for passing filename (with full path) to the command._

Comment: I have gotten it to work in the command line with : 
    -X POST http://api.link.com/here -F 'files=@/path/to/file/here.jpg;type=image.jpg'
so I have just added that onto the on_picture_save line to test. However, I do still need to print my results so I'm not sure how that will work yet. 
Thank you for the input though!

Comment: on https://curl.trillworks.com/ you can convert **curl** command to **requests**

Answer (score 0):

Based on [on_picture_save](https://motion-project.github.io/motion_config.html#on_picture_save) documentation you can use `%f` in command

```
on_picture_save home/pi/Documents/on_picture_save.py %f
```

and it should send filename with full path as argument which you can get as `sys.argv[1]`

```
import sys

print(sys.argv[1])
```

You can also use other [Conversion Specifiers](https://motion-project.github.io/motion_config.html#conversion_specifiers) to send other informations.

---

**BTW:** in documentation for [snapshot_filename](https://motion-project.github.io/motion_config.html#snapshot_filename) you can also see

> A symbolic link called **lastsnap.jpg** is created in the **target_dir** and
>   will always point to the latest snapshot, unless snapshot_filename is
>   exactly 'lastsnap'

so you can get last picture as **lastsnap.jpg**

---

**EDIT:** It seems you have curl command

```
curl -X POST api.link.com/here -F 'files=@/path/to/file/here.jpg;type=image.jpg'
```

which can be converted to Python's requests on http://curl.trillworks.com

and with `sys.argv[1]` it could be

```
import sys
import requests

files = {'files': (sys.argv[1], open(sys.argv[1], 'rb'))}

response = requests.post('http://api.link.com/here', files=files)
data = response.json() 

print(data)
#print(data["???"])
```

But it will have no access to your screen and it you can't see it. You can only save it in file and create other program (which you run on desktop manually)  to read it and display it.

I was using MQTT queue instead of file.

`on_picture_save` was sending data to queue and other local computers at home was running script on desktop which periodically was getting data from queue and displaying on desktop.

[mosquitto](https://mosquitto.org/man/mosquitto_sub-1.html) as server/broker and command line client for tests (or to use with `bash` scripts)
and [Paho MQTT](https://pypi.org/project/paho-mqtt/) as Python's module to work with MQTT.

```
import sys
import requests
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt

files = {'files': (sys.argv[1], open(sys.argv[1], 'rb'))}

response = requests.post('http://api.link.com/here', files=files)
data = response.json() 

client = mqtt.Client()
client.connect('localhost') # or IP of other computer with MQTT server/broker
client.publish('last', sys.argv[1], retain=True)
#client.publish('data', str(data["???"]), retain=True)
```

Comment: thank you for the input, based on the information in my previous comment and your answers, I still need to print my results. I'm not sure how this would work, as it returns in json format, so I do not know where it would print. Thanks again

Comment: I added information about `MQTT` queue which I was using to send information from RPi to few other computers. Other computers would have to run script which periodically check queue and display new information on desktop as popup window.

Comment: got it, Ill look into that. Thank you